# MongoDB Aggregate count based on multiple collections

Tags: mongodb

How to get **`tag`** (from iptag) total based on **`host`** (from services) total ?  Ex: If a **`host`** match **tagAAA** filter condition, total += 1.

```
hostmin <= ip2int(host) <= hostmax
```

---

collection **services**:

```
db.getCollection('services').insert({"host" : "172.21.4.205", "port" : 80, "service" : "http"})
db.getCollection('services').insert({"host" : "172.21.4.97", "port" : 445, "service" : "smb"})
```

collection **iptag**:

```
db.getCollection('iptag').insert({
    "tag" : [ 
        "tagAAA"
    ],
    "hostmin" : 2886991873.0,
    "hostmax" : 2887057406.0,
    "cidr" : "172.20.0.0/16"
}

db.getCollection('iptag').insert({
    "tag" : [ 
        "tagBBB"
    ],
    "hostmin" : 2887057409.0,
    "hostmax" : 2887122942.0,
    "cidr" : "172.21.0.0/16"
}
```

Comment: Not possible with aggregation. Would you consider mapreduce? I'd suggest to add `tags` array to `services` to support this kind of queries.

Comment: If mapreduce can do it, I will. Could you share me how ?

Comment: Yep, with temporary table, i.e. it won't work for operational queries, but if it is one-off BI task, it might be acceptable.

Comment: Hmm. Are the subnet masks all the same? So can we just compare of the first two numbers from the host addresses? If it's needed regularly then there also might be a better way to store the parts of the IP addresses so we can basically use as a "mask" in order to match. And no need for temporary collections.

Comment: Subnet maks are different.  Ex: {cidr: "172.22.0.0/17"}

Comment: The problem is that as of v3.4 the only way to join collection on the db level is aggregation lookup, which supports exact match only. For ranged queries, it is either map-reduce with temporary tables(quite big ones), or application layer (must be quicker).